# Netty udp datagram server setup issue

Tags: java, network-programming, udp, netty, multicast

I have setup a udp datagram server through netty api. During the startup everything is working fine and the server receives all the messages sent to mcast group that the server joins. The problem is after some time hours/or some times couple of days server suddenly stops receiving messages from that mcast group even though the messages are being sent there. Not sure where the problem is hapening. any help will be really appreciated. thanks in advance.

netty version used: **5.0.0.Alpha2**

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.StandardProtocolFamily;
import java.net.StandardSocketOptions;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel;
import java.nio.channels.MembershipKey;


datagramChannel = DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)
                .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                .bind(new InetSocketAddress(groupaddress))
                .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.IP_MULTICAST_IF, network_interface);

                MembershipKey membershipkey = datagramChannel.join(group, network_interface);
                while(true) {

                if (key.isValid()) {
                    byteBuffer.clear();
                    InetSocketAddress socketAddress = (InetSocketAddress) datagramChannel.receive(byteBuffer);
                    byteBuffer.flip();

                    /**   
                        do something on received message
                    **/
                }
            }
```

Comment: any help on this. really stuck on this and unable to get any leads on this

Comment: Without more infos hard to say... That said 5.0.0.Alpha2 is super old. You should use 4.1.4.Final